# using Action class in struts2 to connect to couchDb

Tags: struts2, couchdb

im trying to make a simple login page using struts2 and couch Db as database.i have written a code that checks the values that user enters against the values in the database. I tried connecting to the database first by making a simple java class and retrieving documents that was successful. But when i put the same code in the Action class its giving exception.
Debugging shows that its giving exception at the line where i call the 'Session' object.
My code snippet and stack trace are given below.

```
package net.sarah.struts2;


import java.util.List;

import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Database;
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Document;
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Session;
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.ViewResults;


public class LoginAction {

private String username;
private String password;
public final String LOGIN_ID ="loginid";
public final String LOGIN_PWD ="passwd";

public String execute() {

    try{

    Session dbSession = new Session("localhost", 5984);
    String dbname = "hello-world";
    List <String> listofdb = dbSession.getDatabaseNames();
    System.out.println(listofdb);
    Database db = dbSession.getDatabase(dbname);

    ViewResults results = db.getAllDocuments();
//  System.out.println(results.toString());

    List<Document> studentDocuments = results.getResults();

    for(Document couchDocument: studentDocuments){

        String id = couchDocument.getJSONObject().getString("id");
        Document studentRow = db.getDocument(id);
        System.out.println(studentRow.get("_id"));
        if(studentRow.containsKey(LOGIN_ID)){
            if(LOGIN_ID.equals(username) && LOGIN_PWD.equals(password))

                return "success";

            else
                return "error";


        }
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

        e.getCause();
    }
    return "result";
}
```

**Stack trace -**

INFO: Detected AnnotationActionValidatorManager, initializing it...
Nov 25, 2014 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/Demo] threw exception [java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fourspaces.couchdb.Session
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at net.sarah.struts2.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:404)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:229)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:150)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:48)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:184)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:105)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)

Comment: You're missing the CouchDB library, apparently: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fourspaces.couchdb.Session`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all required libraries in `web-inf/lib`.

This resource could help you [Apache CouchDB](https://sites.google.com/site/arjunwebworld/Home/programming/apache-couchdb).